# 200 return code on 'POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' while NOT logged in

Tags: ajax, security

I noticed the following log entry:

```
111.22.3.444 - - [13/Mar/2015:08:31:00 +0100] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 618 "https://cap5.nl/veiligheidstips-en-voorkom-hacken-van-je-wachtwoord/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36"
```

It is my company website and guaranteed that nobody (including me) was logged in, or using the dashboard. Shouldn't a /wp-admin/.. POST return a 404 or 403 instead of a 200?

Any tips are welcome!

Kind regards,

Gerard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` is the script used by any plugin or theme using WP Ajax API and Ajax actions can be registered for non-logged in users. For example:

```
//For logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
//For non-logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

There is no problem on that. See [WP Ajax documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for more information.

Comment: Good to know, thanx a lot @cybmeta  .. I have a log monitor that loosely watches activity on sites based on /wp-admin/ urls in the access log ... Planning on incorporating Heartbeat API in a plugin for this so the log filter can be removed. Goodluck and thanx again

Comment: sorry, done! :)